# Why am I getting the Missing Operator error?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I keep getting the same error: Missing Operator. I have looked over this code three times and cannot find it. Can someone with a keen eye please help?

```
WHERE ([Letter Status].[Letter_Status] = “Agreed” AND [Research].[Site] = 9)
   OR ([Telephone Status].[Details]= “Agreed” AND [Research].[Site] = 9)
```

Comment: Where's the rest of the statement?  This part seems fine.  Therefore it's likely to be elsewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure about that “”
Maybe is from this post, but change them to "" :

```
WHERE ([Letter Status].[Letter_Status] = "Agreed" AND [Research].[Site] = 9)
   OR ([Telephone Status].[Details]= "Agreed" AND [Research].[Site] = 9)
```

Comment: To clarify, it looks like there are smart quotes around the strings, rather than normal double quotes. (At least, I think that's what Parkyprg is saying)

Comment: I agree.  SO doesn't auto-format those quotes in.  Seems like it could be the issue.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea that mattered. Serves me right for trying to edit SQL in Word. Thanks

Comment: Anyone else find it somewhat comical that both the editor (Word) and database (Access) are MS programs, and they still can't communicate well? ;) (SmartQuotes are teh debil)

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is a misspelled table or field name, two spaces instead of just one, a space instead of "_", any missing letter or something like that.

Create a new query in MS Access and put the whole query in, then run it. The Access GUI most probably tells you more detailed what exactly is missing here.